# Wire size for the communication between generator and ATS

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a 125KVA Generator supplying a 200 Amp ATS. What is the size of communication wire I need between the ATS and the Generator? I was told I need an 18 Gage / 1mm wire; that does sound right.

Comment: What does the Installation Manual specify?

Comment: The installation manual did not specify the gage of wire; I did reach out to the manufacturer, but I got exactly what I could read from the manual, but my question was not answered, the since of comms wire for Genset to ats.

Comment: If the manual is not specific I would use "whatever I have a reel of left over from the 1990s" gage but that's not a great answer so I'll leave it here.  Telephone, Ethernet, Sprinkler, almost anything will probably work.   Some ethernet is 20 or 22 ... I would not use that because it's fragile.   How many signal wires are there?

Comment: What method of protection will you be using for the wire is needed and the requirements for example power / temperature zones, CMP cable can be used in most places type BMU another low power cable that can be buried, the specifications, and how the cables are run make a difference yes you can run these communications cables with the power but the method and power needed is important.